# Oracle Coherence Cache Clustering

Tags: caching, weblogic12c

We have two web-application that use two different version of Embedded Coherence Cache:

- Application 1 with Coherence 3.7.1 (run in JDK7 environment with Weblogic Server 12.1.2)
- Application 2 with Coherence 12.2.1  (run in JDK8 environment with Weblogic Server 12.2.1)

each application deployed in different weblogic server. we try tangosol-override.xml with following configuration for cluster cache of this applications:

Application 1 config:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<coherence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config coherence-operational-config.xsd">
   <cluster-config>
      <unicast-listener>
            <well-known-addresses>
                <socket-address id="1">
                    <address>10.7.17.31</address>
                    <port>8088</port>
                </socket-address>
                <socket-address id="2">
                    <address>10.7.17.31</address>
                    <port>9099</port>
                </socket-address>
            </well-known-addresses>
            <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.localhost">localhost</address>
            <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport">8088</port>
            <port-auto-adjust system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport.adjust">true</port-auto-adjust>
      </unicast-listener>    
   </cluster-config>
  <license-config>
    <edition-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.edition">GE</edition-name>
    <license-mode system-property="tangosol.coherence.mode">prod</license-mode>
  </license-config>
</coherence>
```

Application 2 config:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<coherence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config coherence-operational-config.xsd">
   <cluster-config>
      <unicast-listener>
            <well-known-addresses>
                <socket-address id="1">
                    <address>10.7.17.31</address>
                    <port>8088</port>
                </socket-address>
                <socket-address id="2">
                    <address>10.7.17.31</address>
                    <port>9099</port>
                </socket-address>
            </well-known-addresses>
            <address system-property="tangosol.coherence.localhost">localhost</address>
            <port system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport">9099</port>
            <port-auto-adjust system-property="tangosol.coherence.localport.adjust">true</port-auto-adjust>
      </unicast-listener>    
   </cluster-config>
  <license-config>
    <edition-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.edition">GE</edition-name>
    <license-mode system-property="tangosol.coherence.mode">prod</license-mode>
  </license-config>
</coherence>
```

but all caches are not reachable from another application.
What is the problem?

Comment: I also add following parameters to JAVA_OPTIONS for Weblogic Startup script: -Dtangosol.coherence.cluster=appclustername -Dtangosol.coherence.clusterport=12001

Answer (score 0):

After some research the following solution works for me. I set tangosol-override.xml in startup script of two Weblogic servers and remove other parameters related to coherence cache (-Dtangosol.coherence.override=C:\root\tangosol-coherence-override.xml).

tangosol-coherence-override.xml config File :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<coherence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/coherence/coherence-operational-config coherence-operational-config.xsd">
   <cluster-config>
      <member-identity>
      <cluster-name>appclustername</cluster-name>
    </member-identity>
    <multicast-listener>
      <address>224.1.1.1</address>
      <port>12345</port>
    </multicast-listener>
   </cluster-config>
  <license-config>
    <edition-name system-property="tangosol.coherence.edition">GE</edition-name>
    <license-mode system-property="tangosol.coherence.mode">prod</license-mode>
  </license-config>
</coherence>
```